# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

i am trying to do a post sending a file to a server but i am getting below error

Error:

```
poolKey += options.cert.toString('ascii') + options.key.toString('ascii'
                                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

my nodejs code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

require('ssl-root-cas/latest').inject();

var options = {
  url: 'https://example.com',
  agentOptions: {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('tstr200011')
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

fs.createReadStream('data.xml')
  .pipe(request.post(options).auth('user', 'password', false));
```

Comment: It's trying to access a .cert property on options, which returns undefined. Maybe your cert belongs just inside the options object, not inside the agentOptions object.

Comment: Can you show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: The *options* object (defined using an object literal) doesn't have a property called *key*, so attempting to access it returns *undefined*. Also, there is no *options.cert*, there is *options.agentOptions.cert*.